# Creating and publishing a new layer in Geoserver using Geoserver Rest API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, node-js

I want to publish a new layer in Geoserver. The layer seems unpublished and I get 'Undefined' error.

```
const publish = function () {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const layer = layerName
    const workspace = workspaceName
    const datastore = datastoreName

    let body = `<featureType><name>${layer}</name>
            <nativeBoundingBox>
                <minx>-180</minx>
                <maxx>180</maxx>
                <miny>-90</miny>
                <maxy>90</maxy>
                <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
            </nativeBoundingBox>
            <latLonBoundingBox>
                <minx>-180</minx>
                <maxx>180</maxx>
                <miny>-90</miny>
                <maxy>90</maxy>
                <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
            </latLonBoundingBox>
        </featureType>`

    console.log('body length is ', body.length);


    let options = {
        url: `http://IP:port/geoserver/rest/workspaces/datastores/featuretypes.xml`,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text.xml",
            "Content-Length": body.length
        },
        auth: {
            'user': 'user',
            'pass': 'pass'
        },

    }
    request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
        if (!err && !body) {
            return resolve()

        } else if (!err) {
            let message
            if (resp.statusCode == 400) message = "layer not found"
            else message = body

            return reject({
                status: 404,
                errors: [{
                    messages: [message]
                }]
            })

        } else {
            return reject({
                status: 500,
                errors: [{
                    messages: ["ERRO: connection with geoserver"]
                }]
            })
        }
    })
 })
}

publish().then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: where do you get an undefined error?

Comment: From ' return resolve' I guess.

Comment: Well, he invokes resolve without any arguments so even a correct request will log undefined.

Comment: 'if (!err && !body) {
                return resolve({
                    status: 200,
                    message: 'Layer is published'
                })

            }' still the layer is unpublished.

Comment: Your code worked well. But I still where is my fault

Answer (score 3):

The url seems to be invalid.

I use:
`${geoserver.url}/geoserver/rest/workspaces/${geoserver.namespace}/datastores/${geoserver.store}/featuretypes`

And it's fine. Ex. `localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/testworkspace/datastores/teststore/featuretypes`

And the function I use is:

```
export const publish = (name) => {

    const geoserver = config.geoserver;

    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `${geoserver.url}/geoserver/rest/workspaces/${geoserver.namespace}/datastores/${geoserver.store}/featuretypes`,
            auth: {
                username: geoserver.user,
                password: geoserver.password
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/xml'
            },
            data: `<featureType><name>${name}</name></featureType>`

        })
        .then( response => {
            resolve({
                ok: 1,
                message: `Layer has been published.`
            })
        })
        .catch( err => {
            reject({
                ok: 0,
                message: err.response.data,
            })
        })

    })
}
```

Comment: Let me try yours. But my url is fine like this: `http://IP:port/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<workspaceName>/datastores/<datastoreName>/featuretypes.xml`